# How to launch chromedriver in a different machine and create remotedriver of it

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am in a situation - where chromedriver is located on a different machine and automation code on a different machine, now I want to create driver like:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.172.172.172:9515"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
```

How do I achieve this ?

Even though, after starting chromedriver manually on another machine like ./chromedriver and its started.

Now, I can't browse

> http://172.172.172.172:9515

, though

> http://localhost:9515

works and therefore I can't create the RemoteWebDriver.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you consider executing Selenium Grid Configuration? Thanks

Comment: No, I am avoiding Grid. There should be some other way.